# How can I count duplicate occurrences

Tags: php

here is my associative array, I'm trying to count the occurrences or each of the duplicates here (r-17-VM) (v-2-VM) ignoring "Control domain on host"

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => r-17-VM
            [1] => r-17-VM
            [2] => r-17-VM
            [3] => r-17-VM
            [4] => r-17-VM
            [5] => r-17-VM
            [6] => r-17-VM
            [7] => r-17-VM
            [8] => r-17-VM
            [9] => r-17-VM
            [10] => r-17-VM
            [11] => r-17-VM
            [12] => r-17-VM
            [13] => v-2-VM
            [14] => v-2-VM
            [15] => v-2-VM
            [16] => v-2-VM
            [17] => v-2-VM
            [18] => v-2-VM
            [19] => v-2-VM
            [20] => v-2-VM
            [21] => v-2-VM
            [22] => v-2-VM
            [23] => v-2-VM
            [24] => v-2-VM
            [25] => v-2-VM
            [26] => Control domain on host
            [27] => Control domain on host
            [28] => Control domain on host
            [29] => Control domain on host
            [30] => Control domain on host
            [31] => Control domain on host
        )

)
```

Thank you

Comment: ok, we understand what you want, now we want to understand what you've tried and what kind of problem you have?

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599374/count-string-occurrences-in-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php). It returns an array of the number of times each value is repeated:

```
$frequency = array_count_values($array);
var_dump($frequency);
```

For your array this outputs:

```
array(3) {
  ["r-17-VM"]=>
  int(13)
  ["v-2-VM"]=>
  int(13)
  ["Control domain on host"]=>
  int(6)
}
```

Comment: As I understand, he asked to ignore "Control domain on host". Also according from example, there is multi-demensional array

Comment: @sergio Then he should ignore them. Nothing says he has to use every value in the array.

Comment: Probably ignore not after the result, but have result without it

Comment: Yeah, I can ignore "control domain" after getting results, thanks for your help