# PHP - compare a text field value with an array?

Tags: php, arrays, validation, compare

I'm try to find out how to proceed if I want to compare a text field value with values from an array?

HTML: I have a textbox, and a Check button

```
<form id="text_check" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="e.g. text">
  <button type="button" class="button" name="Check"/>Check</button>
</form>
```

The logical steps should be: 
enter text--> click submit button --> the entered text should be compared with a given array, and return with a positive or negative message...

I am a beginner, so any help is welcome!

Comment: please add more details to your question

Comment: please add some code; what did you try so far?

Comment: http://php.net/in_array

Answer (score 2):

I dont know how your code looks like at the moment but i think you need something like this?
Please respond if you need something else or if i misunderstood your question

```
foreach($yourarray as $value) {
    if($string == $value) {
         // same
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php) function in `PHP`

```
if(in_array("your_string", $array)){
    echo "string matched";
}
```

Comment: This works fine to but the only thing is that you wont be able to count how often it occurs in the array

Comment: @Szenis, you need to see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599374/count-string-occurrences-in-array

Comment: There is no such a thing in requirement. If there is no need to count then `in_array` is good option.

Comment: o nice i did not know that it is posible to count with in_array