# How to get most repeate item on Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays

Good day, Im trying to Get the most repeated inside a `foreach` loop on php. Each array is a cycle of the loop. I need to get the `id` and `name` of the most repeated item, in this example is jake.

This is the loop:

```
    foreach ($json[$key]['data'] as $user){
      var_dump($user);
    }
```

and the output is:

```
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "7032"
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "Jake"
    }
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "1021"
      ["name"]=>
      string(3) "Ana"
    }
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2058"
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "John"
    }
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "7032"
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "Jake"
    }
```

I need the output to be:

```
    $repeated = array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "7032"
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "Jake"
    }
```

Thanks in advance for all your answers.

Comment: Might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/9599420/1507546

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use an explicit loop here:

```
$counts = array_count_values(array_map(function ($user) {
    ksort($user);
    return json_encode($user);   
}, $users));

arsort($counts);

$result = json_decode(key($counts), true);
```

Basically, we map array elements to JSON representations. This is done with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). And it is done because [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) can count only strings or integers. Pay attention that before using [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) we use [`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php). This is needed in case user data is the same but have a different order.

Then we sort descending preserving array keys with [`arsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php).

Finally, we get the first key with [`key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) and decode it get the original array element with [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/43ac6e4c61879d3b808a2980755d3fc486a3d371).

Answer (score 0):

try this step to remove the duplicates from your array,

```
$repeated  = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $repeated)));
```